# SqlDependency.Stop() seems to not work as expected

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldependency, query-notifications

I am developing an application with SQL Dependency feature.

My problem is when I stop application (`SqlDependency.Stop()` method is executed) and I try to run stored procedure with `ANSI_NULLS` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` set to `OFF`, I'm getting error:

> UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'...

Stored procedure is making an update on table which was watched by `SqlDependency`, I do not want to change it because it is from third-party software.

`SqlDependency` uses 'sa' user to connect to DB also I tried other user with no luck.

For now I must restart SQL Server to make it work, but this is unacceptable.

I tried to run this query and kill all subscription:

```
KILL QUERY NOTIFICATION SUBSCRIPTION @Id
```

but I still get same error.

Can someone help me with resolving this problem ?

Comment: What ahppens if you run the SP in SQL management studio, do you get the same error? On the face of it it looks as though the SP is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I get same error, but after server restart it works correctly seems then sqldependency stops working.